# Gradeaverage app won´t start

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation, average

I am trying to make this app that calculates your grade average (based on the Swedish grade system) and I have made the graphical layout and written the java code in eclipse that I think is right, but when I try to launch it in the emulator it won´t work. The app starts, but its only a black screen. This is my first app and my first programming project so I don´t really know what I have done wrong.

It is supposed to be three edittexts where you put the amount of points you have with a cerrtain grade (we have three grades) and then it should multiply the points with the 10, 15 or 20 depending on what grade it is and then divide by the total amount of points. I dont know if that makes sense, but the maxmimum grade is supposed to be 20 (all mvgs). I made a similar app in C# and it works, but Im guessing things are done a little different when it comes to android and java.

```
package com.dlol.gradeaverage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GradeaverageActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText1, editText2, editText3;
String gtext, vgtext, mvgtext, str;
Double gpoäng, vgpoäng, mvgpoäng;
Double gvärde, vgvärde, mvgvärde;
Double allapoäng, allavärde;
Double snittbetyg;
Button button1;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

 editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
 editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
 editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3); 

 gtext = editText1.getText().toString();
 vgtext = editText2.getText().toString();
 mvgtext = editText3.getText().toString();

 gpoäng = Double.parseDouble(gtext);
 vgpoäng = Double.parseDouble(vgtext);
 mvgpoäng = Double.parseDouble(mvgtext);

 gvärde = gpoäng*10;
 vgvärde = vgpoäng*15;
 mvgvärde = mvgpoäng*20;

 allapoäng = (gpoäng + vgpoäng + mvgpoäng);
 allavärde = (gvärde + vgvärde + mvgvärde);

 snittbetyg = (allavärde / allapoäng);
 str = "Ditt snitt är " + snittbetyg;

 button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  

 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
});
}}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/info_text_G" 
    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text">        
</EditText>/

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/info_text_VG" 
    android:textSize="16sp" />

 <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text">        
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/info_text_MVG" 
    android:textSize="16sp">        
</TextView>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text">        
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, GradeaverageActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Gradeaverage</string>
<string name="info_text_G">Skriv in antal G-poäng</string>
<string name="info_text_VG">Skriv in antal VG-poäng</string>
<string name="info_text_MVG">Skriv in antal MVG-poäng</string>
<string name="Button">Räkna ut snitt!</string>
</resources>
```

02-05 17:07:06.184: D/AndroidRuntime(1230): Shutting down VM
02-05 17:07:06.184: W/dalvikvm(1230): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
02-05 17:07:06.184: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dlol.gradeaverage/com.dlol.gradeaverage.GradeaverageActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:258)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:323)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.dlol.gradeaverage.GradeaverageActivity.onCreate(GradeaverageActivity.java:37)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
02-05 17:07:06.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     ... 11 more
02-05 17:07:06.225: I/dalvikvm(1230): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-05 17:07:06.244: I/dalvikvm(1230): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-05 17:07:06.344: I/jdwp(1230): received file descriptor 24 from ADB
02-05 17:07:06.354: W/System.err(1230): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
02-05 17:07:06.354: W/System.err(1230): Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined

Comment: Do you start the app and then the screen goes black(with no force close errors?)? Do you have other activities in the app or `GradeaverageActivity` is the only one?

Comment: Yeah exactly, it starts and it says "Gradeaverage" at the top of the screen but everything else is black. Then it says "The application Gradeaverage (process com.dlol.gradeaverage) has stopped unexpectedly. please try again". I don't think there are any other activities but I'm not sure. As far as I know I have not created any more activities.

Comment: You have an error somewhere in your code. Edit your answer and add the `Logcat` containing the error.

Comment: the logcat is not showing any errors but the sonsole is saying "[2012-02-05 16:58:08 - Gradeaverage] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.LAUNCHER} comp={com.dlol.gradeaverage/com.dlol.gradeaverage.GradeaverageActivity} }
[2012-02-05 16:58:08 - Gradeaverage] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Comment: I tried it some more and now does the logcat include errors, posted them in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `NumberFormatException` because when you create the `Activity`(`onCreate()` method) you already try to parse the text from the `EditText`(you have emty text `""` and trying to parse it to `Double` will trow an `Exception`) although you didn't entered any numbers yet. You have to move the code for calculating the grades on the button's `OnCLickListener` like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    

     editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
     editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
     editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3); 

     button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  

     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
    gtext = editText1.getText().toString();
     vgtext = editText2.getText().toString();
     mvgtext = editText3.getText().toString();

     gpoäng = Double.parseDouble(gtext);
     vgpoäng = Double.parseDouble(vgtext);
     mvgpoäng = Double.parseDouble(mvgtext);

     gvärde = gpoäng*10;
     vgvärde = vgpoäng*15;
     mvgvärde = mvgpoäng*20;

     allapoäng = (gpoäng + vgpoäng + mvgpoäng);
     allavärde = (gvärde + vgvärde + mvgvärde);

     snittbetyg = (allavärde / allapoäng);
     str = "Ditt snitt är " + snittbetyg;
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    });
    }
```

Comment: YES! It totally works now, both on the emulator and on my phone! Thank you so much sir, I am forever greatful for your help :D

Comment: I marked it correct and when I get 15 reputation I will upvote it too ;)